# Cannot browse to network shares but can ping and RDP into machines on LAN

Tags: windows-xp, networking, troubleshooting

I am using Windows XP SP3. I cannot browse to network shares via explorer, using machine name or IP. I can ping all machines by name and connect via RDP by name with no problem. I have changed nothing on the LAN or any network settings on any machine since it was working ok. Does anyone have any suggestions or ideas why it would suddenly stop working in this way?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be anything, but the quickest things to do is to run the network setup wizard on each machine (even if you only click next at each step) or enable advanced files sharing as this does a few tasks such as:

- Enables guest account for network access
- Sets up security policy
- Stops a lot of headaches of looking in settings for many hours!

After you have done this, you should be able to access any other machine that has already run the wizard.

Comment: well whatever it was, that has resolved it, thanks :)